# Given the following Leaflet.Draw example on Plunker, how would I catch the rectangle created event and action on it?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Plunker Example:
[Leaflet Draw plugin with OSM map](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQd8Y6TX7sufb5N8rQqY?p=preview)

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib });
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', { layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(52.105289405897, 5.2629891004852425), zoom: 13 });
console.log('map ready');

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();

var coords = [new L.latLng(51.2, 4.5), new L.latLng(51.2, 4.6), new L.latLng(51.2, 4.9)];
var poly = new L.Polyline(coords, {
color: 'blue',
opacity: 1,
weight: 5
});

drawnItems.addLayer(poly);


map.addLayer(drawnItems);


var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        position: 'right',
        polygon: {
            title: 'Polygon',
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {
                color: '#b00b00',
                timeout: 1000
            },
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55'
            },
            showArea: true
        },
        polyline: {
            metric: false
        },
        circle: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#662d91'
            }
        }
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});

map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    console.log('adding layer', layer, drawnItems);
});
```

I need to catch a created rectangle and ultimately make a file out of it's coordinates, but for now I'm trying to figure out how to catch the event and output the rectangles coordinates to the console.

Forgive me, still stepping into Javascript. Thanks

--Edit--
So I see how to log this event to console, but I don't clearly see how to access the lat/lng info from the event.

```
map.on('draw:rectangle-created', function (e) {
    console.log(e.rectangle-created);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `draw:created` event and check if type is a rectangle:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'rectangle') {
        // It's a rectangle, do stuff
        console.log(layer.getLatLngs());
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    console.log('adding layer', layer, drawnItems);
});
```

You can access the rectangle's coordinates by calling the `getLatLngs` method. It returns an array of `L.LatLng` objects:

```
rectangle.getLatLngs().forEach(function (latlng) {
    console.log(latlng.lat); //latitude
    console.log(latlng.lng); //longitude
});
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

Comment: How do I access each lat/lng pair of what's returned from .getLatLngs()? When I iterate over it, I return a lot of excess layer information.

Comment: More specifically I guess would be:
How do I access a Lat or a Lng inside of layer.getLatLngs()[0];

Comment: Thanks! That did it.